# the probability that the product of all the numbers is $\color{red}{irrational}$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

When i  get around the deep of stacke exchange , i found a  nice question and wanted to change it a little

$\color{blue}{Original:}$ [Three dice having sides labelled $e,i,π,1,0,\sqrt2$ are rolled. Find the probability of getting the product of the three results a real number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/three-dice-having-sides-labelled-e-i-%cf%80-1-0-sqrt2-are-rolled-find-the-probabi)

$\color{green} { Question:}$  There are three fair six-sided dice with sides $0,1,e,π,i,\sqrt{2}$. If these dice are rolled, the probability that the product of all the numbers is $\color{red}{irrational}$ can be expressed as $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive, co-prime integers. What is $a+b$?

$\color{orange} { Solution:}$

$\color{pink} { Firstly:}$ All possibilities $-$
rationals

$\color{pink} { Secondly:}$ The number of rationals $=$ (At lest one zero) $+$ (two $\sqrt{2}$,$1$) $+$ (two $i$, $1$) $=$ $(6^3 - 5^3)$  $+$ ($\frac{3!}{2! \times 1!}$) $+$ ($\frac{3!}{2! \times 1!}$) $=$ $91+3+3 =97$

$\color{pink} { Thirdly:}$ $6^3 - 97 =119$ ,so $\frac{119}{216} =119+216=335$

Is my solution correct ? If not, can you share your approach ?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct

Comment: Rational numbers and irrational numbers are both a subset of real numbers.  If the number of dice that show $i$ is odd, then the product will be neither rational nor irrational, since the product won't be a real number.  This **anomaly** has an easy **remedy** by editing your query to indicate that $iy$ (where $y$ is a real) will be **construed to be** rational(/irrational) if and only if $y$ is rational(/irrational).  Without such a query-edit-remedy, you are left with the anomaly.

Comment: Re my previous comment, it occurs to me that the OP might prefer to **preserve** the anomaly.  Then, the question becomes what is the probability that the product is **both real and irrational**.

Comment: We do not know whether $e\cdot \pi$ is irrational. Hence, the exercise is ill-posed. The case $e,\pi,1$ is undetermined.

Comment: @Peter +1: wow: you opened a can of worms.

Comment: your solution is correct. I was reading your modified question incorrectly as I was still reading it in the light of the earlier question you had put up a while earlier that you later deleted and posted this one.

Comment: @MathLover What about my comments, or the comment of Peter?

Comment: The point from Peter is a good one but matter of debate which is endless. The point that you make is something that the OP must clarify in the question, how OP would consider complex numbers vs. real numbers. In fact a well written question would also clarify if $e.\pi$ is being considered rational or irrational.

Comment: @Peter Suppose that it is assumed that $(e \times \pi)$ is irrational?  Does this imply that $(e \times \pi^2)$ is also irrational?  Same question,re $(e^2 \times \pi).$

Comment: @user2661923 I think, we cannot determine those cases either, but I am not sure and have no reference.

Comment: $e,\pi,\sqrt{2}$ is probably open as well. We have to assume many products to be irrational to make the question well-posed.

Comment: @MathLover - what debate is there over whether *we know* that $e\cdot \pi$ is irrational? If no one has proved (or disproved) irrationality, then it is quite clear that *we do not know*. If there is a valid proof extant, then *we know*. There may be some debate over proof validity, but in Math, such debates settle out pretty quickly, instead of being "endless".